# Java не находит указанный файл для считывания

Tags: java, exe

Использую InteliJ IDEA для создания .exe файла, чтобы запустить свое приложение. У меня в папке src хранятся текстовые документы, которые необходимо считать. При компиляции указан абсолютный путь до этих файлов и программа работает как положено. Но при запуске exe файла приложения, он не может по абсолютному пути найти эти файлы, но если прописать полный путь к файлу, то считывает и все работает как надо.

```
String path = new File("src/sample/info/Celebrations.txt").getAbsolutePath();

        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream(path), "utf8"));
        String line = reader.readLine();

        if(line != null && !line.trim().isEmpty()) {listHolidays.add(line);}

        while (line != null) {

            line = reader.readLine();

            if(line != null && !line.trim().isEmpty()) {listHolidays.add(line);}

        }
```

Таким образом сохраняю путь до текстового файла. Что нужно сделать чтобы и при запуске через .exe файл все считывалось правильно?

Comment: _не может по абсолютному пути найти эти файлы, но если прописать полный путь к файлу_ - полный путь и абсолютный это одно и то же.

Comment: Если у вас файлы не меняются в процессе работы, то имеет смысл их перенести в ресурсы (они будут упакованы в jar, а потом в exe), в коде получать к ним доступ через `getClass().getClassLoader().getResource(...)`

Comment: Перенес текстовый файл в jar, а можно пример какой-нибудь как реализовать это в коде? Я как понимаю там переменная типа URl, а мне надо же получить путь и считать информацию из файла. Я не знаю как это реализовать(

Comment: @insolor Подскажите, как мне изменить мой код чтобы я мог считать из jar файла.
Код дополнил выше.